# Множественное скачивание файлов jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

На странице есть ссылка для скачивания файлов

https://screenshots.firefox.com/2xc8Z1kIxP9gXjZp/127.0.0.1

Мне нужно по клику на кнопку Download All загрузить все файлы.

Делаю это js

```
 $('#download-all').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.js-customer-file').each(function(index, value){
            setTimeout(function() {
                 //window.location.href = $(value).attr('href');
                 //$(value).trigger( "click" );
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

При редиректе скачивается только последний файл в списке. При клике вообще ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема? Можно ли так вообще делать?

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте

```
 $('#download-all').on('click', function () {
     $(this).closest('div').find('.js-customer-file').each(function (index, value) {
        window.open(value, '_blank');
     });
 });
```